# How to activate Deviceadmin programmatically in android studio?

Tags: android

In my application, I want to lock lost mobile phones remotely from another mobile phone through SMS code. So when my application is installed it will ask for the code and save it. When the mobile phone is lost, if we send the same code (saved one) through SMS the lost mobile should be locked.

So I am implementing the code in `BroadcastReceiver` class but when I try to lock the mobile phone, it is showing that `DeviceAdmin` is inactive and that the phone cannot be locked.

Here is my code in `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
if(message.equals(wipemsg)){
    Intent lockintent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    lockintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(lockintent);
    mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(context, DeviceAdminSample .class);
    boolean active = mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdmin);
    if (active) {
        mDPM.lockNow();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "not locked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The Toast appears as "not locked" every time I execute.

How to make that `DeviceAdmin` active?

Comment: We need more code, how is your deviceadmin being connected, is the onEnabled function being triggered?

Comment: How to connect device admin.No i dint trigger onEnabled function. But how it is to be triggered. i have created an object for that class and trying to invoke that function but its not working.

Comment: i have created this class but never used it                                       public class DeviceAdminSample extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onEnabled(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.device_admin_enabled,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onDisabled(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.device_admin_disabled,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

Comment: Iam activiting deviceadmin dircetly without use of checkbox. so i directly wrote intent .. code after comparison.but my deviceadmin is not becoming active eventhough i create a intent object and started an activity.